# react-native-share The operation couldn’t be completed. Not installed

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-share

I installed the react-native-share package but I can't share directly to Twitter on IOS. It's working perfectly on Android.

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ECOM.RNSHARE1",
    "domain": "com.rnshare",
    "message": "The operation couldn’t be completed. Not installed",
    "nativeStackIOS": [
      "0   myApp                            0x0000000102cd4ae0 RCTJSErrorFromCodeMessageAndNSError + 112",
      "1   myApp                            0x0000000102cd4a20 RCTJSErrorFromNSError + 256",
      "2   myApp                            0x0000000102c64f88 __41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke_4.110 + 152",
      "3   myApp                            0x0000000102bb82cc -[GenericShare shareSingle:failureCallback:successCallback:serviceType:inAppBaseUrl:] + 2156",
      "4   myApp                            0x0000000102bbbb67 -[RNShare shareSingle:failureCallback:successCallback:] + 855",
      "5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001119aa47c __invoking___ + 140",
      "6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001119a7872 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 305",
      "7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001119a7b05 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 70",
      "8   myApp                            0x0000000102c674e6 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 2534",
      "9   myApp                            0x0000000102c6b97a _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicEiN12_GLOBAL__N_117SchedulingContextE + 1402",
      "10  myApp                            0x0000000102c6b22c _ZZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEiENK3$_0clEv + 156",
      "11  myApp                            0x0000000102c6b189 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 25",
      "12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114993876 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12",
      "13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114994a56 _dispatch_client_callout + 8",
      "14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001149a1e20 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1073",
      "15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011191185d __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9",
      "16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011190c0ba __CFRunLoopRun + 2772",
      "17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011190b103 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567",
      "18  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001156e1cd3 GSEventRunModal + 139",
      "19  UIKitCore                           0x0000000126758e63 -[UIApplication _run] + 928",
      "20  UIKitCore                           0x000000012675da53 UIApplicationMain + 101",
      "21  myApp                            0x00000001026dde38 main + 104",
      "22  dyld                                0x000000010de47e1e start_sim + 10",
      "23  ???                                 0x0000000205a0351e 0x0 + 8684320030",
      "24  ???                                 0x00000002059fe000 0x0 + 8684298240"
    ],
    "userInfo": { "NSLocalizedFailureReason": "Not installed" }
  }
}
```

I only got this error when I use the Share.shareSingle() function to share on Twitter, not when I use the Share.open().

My code:

```js
const shareToTwitter = imageUri => {
    let options = {
      title: 'Share Title',
      message: messageToShare,
      url: imageUri,
      social: Share.Social.TWITTER,
      type: 'image/png',
    };
    Share.shareSingle(options)
      .then(res => {
        ignoreShare();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        err && console.log('error in Share.open: ', err);
        ignoreShare();
      });
  };
```

I guess it's a problem with iOS permissions and I already tried everything found here [Github issue](https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/271)

And that is my info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Kryll.io</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs permission to save your screenshots on your device</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Roboto-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Italic.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-LightItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-Thin.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>viber</string>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
        <string>instagram</string>
        <string>instagram-stories</string>
        <string>lineauth</string>
        <string>line3rdp.com.zhiliaoapp.musically</string>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150714</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
        <string>snapchat</string>
        <string>twitter</string>
        <string>twitterauth</string>
        <string>bandapp</string>
        <string>kakaostory</string>
        <string>navercafe</string>
        <string>naverblog</string>
        <string>vkauthorize</string>
        <string>vk</string>
        <string>vk-share</string>
        <string>fb</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
        <string>fb-messenger</string>
        <string>comgooglemaps</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The package is [here](https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/install) and I installed it simply with:

```
npm i react-native-share --save
npx pod-install
```

Configuration:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.4",
"react-native-share": "^7.3.7",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we found a workaround for the shareSingle with Twitter, by changing a little piece of code in GenericShare.m from the package:

Line 20:

From that:

```swift
    if(![serviceType isEqualToString:@"com.apple.social.twitter"] && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:inAppBaseUrl]]) {
```

To:

```swift
    if([serviceType isEqualToString:@"com.apple.social.twitter"] && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:inAppBaseUrl]]) {
```

Just remove the exclamation mark after the if.

This is probably a temporary fix, but it works for now.